# How to add visited pages to magento session?

Tags: session

I want to add an array of visited pages by a user to magento session, when the user first time visits the page. i have tried this

```
 $current_page[]= Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyval();
     Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsMyval();     
      $Current= $this->getPopupBlock();//get current page identifier

       if (in_array($Current, $current_page)) 
        {
          //do something
        }else 
        {          
          array_push($current_page, $Current);
        }
       echo "<pre>"; print_r($current_page); echo "</pre>"; //just for debuging
    php Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyval($current_page);
```

but on every page refresh, i am getting this output

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => home
                )

            [1] => category
        )

    [1] => category
)
```

Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: Why do you unset the value in session?

Comment: to avoid duplication in setting session at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a array of $current_page and add a array filter at start of function. Also you should check that if the array is empty the you assign session data to a variable with braces[]. And if the array is not Empty then you assign current page session to a variable and push it in array.
 Your Code become like this.
 Its works for me try this.

      `$current_pag[] = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('Myval');
      $current_pag = array_filter($current_pag);
      if (empty($current_pag)) 
         {
           $current_page[] = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
                 ->getData('Myval');
    }
      else{
       $current_page = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
                ->getData('Myval');
       }
       $Current= $this->getCurrentPage();
            if (in_array($Current, $current_page)) 
                {
                    $status=0;
                }else 
                {
                    $status=1;
                    array_push($current_page, $Current);
                }
               Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('Myval',''); 
         Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('Myval',$current_page);`